# Hero Animation intially overflows then adjusts

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Building a hero animation for list->detail, with responsive layouts for screen sizes.
Initially upon transitioning I get a brief renderflex error then it adjusts and is fine.

I solved this with the column (phone) layout with a ListView but the other layout is a row (side by side screens). No matter what combination of flexes and expanded and Lists and every other widget I could think of, I can't get it solved. Thanks

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
            child: Hero(
              tag: content.timestamp,
              child: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 600
                  ? ... Column layout
                  : Row(
                      children: [
                        FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                          placeholder: 'assets/icons/barc-lodge.png',
                          image: 'https://www.barclodge.ca/android/diary/${content.image}',
                          width: 300,
                        ),
                 // Expanded exists to wrap text
                        Expanded(
                          child: diaryContent(context, content),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
            ),
            onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
    );
  }

  Widget diaryContent(BuildContext ctx, BarcLodgeDiary words) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0),
          child: Text(words.title, style: Theme.of(ctx).textTheme.headline1),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
          child: Text('${words.datestamp} at ${words.timestamp}', style: Theme.of(ctx).textTheme.caption),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Text(words.diaryentry, style: Theme.of(ctx).textTheme.bodyText1),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I did not try apparently in a couple hours was GridView. Remove the Expanded, change Row to GridView.count and everything is a-ok.

Answer (score 0):

This might be your issue. The `Hero` widget needs a `Material` widget inside it to provide a canvas for the splash, you can read about it in the docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations#photohero-class). The section is about building your own hero widget but I think it still applies, if this doesn't fix your issue, try wrapping the `Hero` widget with the `Material` widget.